# Group Replace in javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have anchor tags in my html. The value of `href` attribute starts with either `'` or `"`. I want to replace `javascript:window.location.replace('` href value and `')`.

sample_input

`"<a href="xyz.com" attr="pqrs"> text </a> \n <a href='xyz1.com' attr="pqrs"> text1 </a>"`

desired_output

`"<a href="javascript:window.location.replace('xyz.com')" attr="pqrs"> text </a> \n <a href='"xyz.com"' attr="pqrs"> text1 </a>"`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/128165 for why you should not use regex

Comment: You can directly use the single quote inside double (like `"<a href='xyz.com' attr='pqrs'>"`) why you need to replace it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
sample_input.replace(new RegExp('(<a.?href=)([\'\"])(.?)([\'\"])', 'g'), "\$1\"javascript:window.location.replace('\$3')\"")
```